# Javascript Error 424(Failed dependency)

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

i am getting this error from browser console in an ajax call.
This is where the event take place:

```
<input id="txtCuilCuit" maxlength="11" name="cuit" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="CUIL/CUIT" value="{{numeroCUIT}}" data-num>
```

And this is the js code for the event of this item:

```
$('#txtCuilCuit').on('blur',function(event) {
         isFormValido();
        validarCuilCuit(event);
        });
```

An this is the method where the error appears:

```
function validarCuilCuit(event)
    {
      event.preventDefault();

      var cbu = $('#txtCbu').val();
      var cuilCuit = $('#txtCuilCuit').val();
      var hashCuenta  = $('#hashCuenta').val();

      var isValido = isFormValido();

      if (!isValido)//(cbu == '' && cuilCuit == '')
        return

      util.ajax('GET', null, '/api/infoBancaria/validarCbu?cuilCuit='+cuilCuit+'&numeroCBU='+cbu+'&hashCuenta='+hashCuenta,
        function(event) {
          //alert('cbu ok'+event);
          if (event.cbuCuentaBanco != null
            || typeof(event.cbuCuentaBanco) != 'undefined'
            || event.cbuCuentaBanco != '') {

            $('#descripcionCuenta').css('visibility', 'inherit');
            setFormulario(event);
            //$('#idCuenta').val(event.idCuenta);
            //$('#hashCuenta').val(event.hashCuenta);
            //--inputs

            $('#btnValidarCBU').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#btnEditarCBU').css('visibility', 'inherit');
            $('#txtCbu').prop('disabled',true);
            $('#btnGuardarCambios').prop('disabled',false);
          } else {
            $('#descripcionCuenta').css('visibility', 'hidden');
          }
          //$('#msg').hide();
          util.marcarValidacionCampoByParent('infoBan','cuit',false,'');
        },
        function(event) {
          //alert('Aca hay que hacer algo con el error del cbu');
          $('#descripcionCuenta').css('visibility', 'hidden');

         /*$('#msg').html(event.responseJSON.message);
          $('#msg').show();*/
          util.marcarValidacionCampoByParent('infoBan','cuit',true,(JSON.parse(event.responseText)).message,util.align.Right);


        }
      );
    }
```

Result error:

```
  GET http://127.0.0.1:9999/api/infoBancaria/validarCbu?cuilCuit=305404&numeroCBU=3312123213212321132321&hashCuenta=41ed736322e7a10d0e0d85cf51c52979 424 (Failed Dependency)
```

I´m getting the result i want but this error appears in the console.

I don´t know what to do, any idea?

Comment: I think problem on server side. What server do you use on http://127.0.0.1:9999 ?

Comment: I´am using Grunt tecnology as server for the front part of the app at port 9999 and Jboss for back part at port 8686.

Comment: Server response with the status 424 (Failed Dependency), it means server side (Grunt technology) has some problems (dependency error) and works with errors. Try make requist to another server (local) and check if erorr has gone.

Comment: I can´t use another server, it is my job app, and it use this, i must solve this whithout changing tecnologies.

Comment: I advice you try to search problem in your server side.